# Facebook show friends posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

One of our feature is to display the posts of our facebook friend. And that is made possible by Facebook Query Langauge [FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql). Unfortunately FQL has been deprecated by FB in favor of Graph API which has stricter permissions. A possible replacement is the Graphs API user_posts permission where we can query user posts via [user feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/user/feed).

However the docs says:

"Your app needs user_posts permission from the person who created the post or the person tagged in the post."

Are there still alternative to get get user posts even without users permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only should be able to access friend's posts if your friends gave at least `user_friends` and `user_posts` permission to the same app.

If so, you'll only have access to those friend's posts, not to all your friends. An no, there's no workyround. Facebook did this on purpose with the introduction of the Graph API v2.0.